# How do I set CORS with Formidable in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cors, formidable

I thought I should send the CORS header in the response, something like the code below. But this does not work, I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

How should I do it?

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.encoding = 'utf-8';
form.uploadDir = "./testup";
form.keepExtensions = true;
form.type = 'multipart';
form.on("fileBegin", (name, file) => {
    file.path = path.join(__dirname, "testup", file.name);
});

form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("form.parse:", err); 
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST,GET",
            'content-type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    }
});
```

PS: I am posting with JavaScript "fetch", not XMLHttpRequest (which of course should not matter...)

---

EDIT: Sorry, it was a typo. I did not realize that I got a 404 before the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.". So I looked for something complicated.